# Image Editor in Flex + PHP

Tags: php, apache-flex, imagemagick

We have an image editor in Flex to add text and other changes. Once all the changes are complete, we need to save this to the server.

We are using php to save the images by accepting coordinates from flex about what all edits are made for that image. Using this we are editing that image using imagick function in PHP. But the problem is output is different from what we see in flex. The issue is mainly with text alignment in flex editor and in the output we get after editing in php.

Is there any other way to do this without making the user to wait for a long time to save the images?

or

Is it possible to get the correct coordinates of text from that flex editor. Our issue is flex is passing the x,y of the container of that text editor. For this reason, test is misaligned in the output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your problem is with lining up the text but it is definitely possible to line up the text perfectly.  You can use actionscript to get the exact location of each line of text and then just redraw that making sure you are using the correct sizes and locations.  If you are rotating the math will get a little bit messier but it is definitely doable.

Comment: @M.Laing While we save that image in PHP, flex is giving the x and y of the container instead of x and y of the text.

Comment: Then use flex to send the x and y coordinate of the actual line of text instead.  I know there is a way to do that.  I can look and get back to you tomorrow or you can try googling around for it.  But I've done it before so I know its possible to send the location fo the line, not just the container.  I added an answer with links to the functions needed to do this.

Comment: @M.Laing We were able to get starting x position. But not getting Y position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use the [TextLineMetrics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html). 
You can get this information by using the [getLineMetrics()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getLineMetrics%28%29) Function.

Take a look at those links and if you still have some questions let me know and I'll try to help you figure them out.  But basically you can get the line metrics of the textfield and then send that information to the php instead of just the containers position.  You will need to do this for each line in the textfield.  The `TextLineMetrics` will help you with positioning and sizing of the text to make sure you can line it up correctly.

Comment: We were able to get starting x position with these functions. But not getting Y position.

Comment: You need to use the Y position of the container and then add the height of each line before the one you are on, plus the leadings and other things shown in the image in one of those links I provided and you should be able to calculate the Y position.

Comment: We used these calculations to get the Y, but not getting it correctly.

Comment: We think we are almost there with finding out Y co-ordinates. Now we have another issue. Same text with same font and size is showing in different size in flex and php. For example, when we trite text "Hello" in Flex with Arial, 20 as fontsize. We are passing these values to php to write this in server. When it writes same text with same font and size, text sizes are different in what we see in flex and the output generated by PHP. Any Ideas??

Comment: Yea like I said you need to use the height and width of the line of text, not just the size because the font size will be a different size.  You could mess around and try to find a conversion or you could just specify the height and width of each line